# Is there a way to build JRuby jars for lower Java versions on mac?

Tags: ruby, macos, jruby, java

I am playing around with JRuby with mac, and have installed 1.7 JDK, and created a jar file to see how it would go on other macs, but since the current Mac's default Java is 1.6, the jars could not be opened.

I tried to install 1.6 JDK, but couldn't find a mac version for it, is it possible to build for Java 1.6, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: *"have installed 1.7 JDK"*  Is that the one from Oracle or Apple?  I know Oracle's Java compiler supports options to allow cross-compilation (compiling for lower versions), but am not sure about others.

Comment: Downlaoded the one from Oracle, thanks for the info, at least it seems I have a chance. Good news